# Trying to prove the method used for solving absolute value inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose want to solve $|f(x)| < a$ for $x$ In a math course, you will learn that you simplify solve for (*) $-a < f(x) < a$ by solving for $f(x)<a$ and $f(x)>-a$ then taking the interesection of both solutions.  This seems iffy though, because of the whole absolute value of $f(x)$ that will change our expression suddenly around $f(x)=0$

So I tried to "prove" this method works:

For our solution to be actually valid we have to solve for (**) $0 \le f(x) < a$ and take the union with $-a<f(x)<0$ Surprisingly for me we get the same as (*) here.

So I guess what is confusing me is the fact that $-a<f(x)<a$ is the same as $(f(x)<a) \cap (f(x)>-a)$  WITH the absolute value messing things up there around $f(x)=0$?

How can this be proved?

Comment: Your notation is odd, but understandable, Anyway, what you ask about is true pretty much by definition. The statement $-a<f(x)<a$ is an abbreviation for $-a<f(x)\land f(x)<a$ and the definition of $\cap$ takes care of linking the statements.

Comment: If I am reading correctly, it appears your issue is concerned with $x=0$.What do you specifically think is incorrect or worrisome about 0 when using the intersection definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one thing to keep in mind is that, for any real number $y,$ we have $$-|y|\le y\le|y|,\tag{$\star$}$$ which is fairly straightforward to prove by cases (depending on the sign of $y$).

---

Now, if we're given $$|y|<a,$$ then adding $-|y|-a$ to both sides yields the equivalent $-a<-|y|,$ and by $(\star),$ it follows that $$-a<-|y|\le y\le|y|<a,$$ whence $$-a<y<a.$$

---

On the other hand, if we're given $$-a<y<a,$$ then we readily have $-a<y<0$ or $0\le y<a.$ In the former case, $|y|=-y$ by definition, and since $-a<y,$ then adding $|y|+a$ to both sides yields the equivalent $|y|<a$. In the latter case, $|y|=y,$ so already $|y|<a.$

---

Thus, for all real $a,y,$ we have $$|y|<a\Longleftrightarrow-a<y<a.\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$

---

As far as the intuition goes, think of $|y|$ as "the distance from $y$ to $0,$" at which point $(\heartsuit)$ becomes almost trivial. The absolute value doesn't "mess things up" at all. Put verbally, you're trying to prove that $f(x)$ is less than $a$ away from $0$ if and only if $f(x)$ lies between $-a$ and $a,$ which shouldn't seem strange.

---

If you want to think in terms of intersections and unions, the kicker (that you've already discovered) is that for any positive real $a,$ we have $$(-a,+\infty)\cap(-\infty,a)=(-a,a)=(-a,0)\cup[0,a).$$